# How to create a list from pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a set of excel files that I am trying to loop through to create a series of pandas dataframes (as below). Each dataframe is named 1001, 1002, 1003, etc.

```
store_1001 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(1001.xls))
Print(store_1001)

    0    Apples Oranges Grapes Mango Total  
    9      15     16      1     0     32

store_1002 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(1002.xls))
Print(store_1002)

    0    Apples Oranges Grapes Mango Total  
    9      35     8      21     28     92

store_1003 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(1003.xls))
Print(store_1003)

    0    Apples Oranges Grapes Mango Total  
    9      0     0       0      0     0
```

I want to pull the total from each data frame to create list. My final goal to create a new dataframe with the old dataframe name and corresponding value.

```
0 Store Items
1 1001   32 
2 1002   92 
3 1003   0
```

So far I can make the first column of this table, but I am stuck at pulling the index from one table at a time (not sure how to loop through). Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Difficult to answer concretely without example data, but one approach may be to `assign` the store ID to each dataframe, join, and summarize with `groupby` or `pivot_table`.

Comment: I added some extra data to hopefully make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the excel files are in a single, separate directory, you can get the list of all the excel files using the `listdir` method from the `os` module. The code for is looks something like this:

```py
import os
file_list = os.listdir(path)
```

Here `path` is the path to the directory that contains all the excel files for store data. Once you have the file list, you can just loop through it and get/process the data for each dataframe.

I have put out a small example for you below.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

df_list = []
df_total = []

for file_name in os.listdir(path):  # path -> path to the directory that contains all the excel files
    # exception handling in case directory has non-excel files
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    except:
        continue
    # get the df total here (I'm assuming your dataframe has a single row as per the example)
    total = df.iloc[0]['total']

    # adding file name to df_list
    df_list.append(os.path.splitext(file_name)[0])  # removes extension, keeping just file name 

    # adding df total to df_total list
    df_total.append(total)

# creating the final dataframe with total from each mini-dataframe
total_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "store": df_list,
    "items": df_total,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each Excel file is named with the store number:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(f'{n}.xls').assign(store=n)
               for n in [1001,1002,1003], axis=0)
```

```
# using sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 9}, 'Apples': {0: 15}, 'Oranges': {0: 16}, 'Grapes': {0: 1}, 'Mango': {0: 0}, 'Total': {0: 32}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 9}, 'Apples': {0: 35}, 'Oranges': {0: 8}, 'Grapes': {0: 21}, 'Mango': {0: 28}, 'Total': {0: 92}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 9}, 'Apples': {0: 0}, 'Oranges': {0: 0}, 'Grapes': {0: 0}, 'Mango': {0: 0}, 'Total': {0: 0}})
df = pd.concat([df1.assign(store=1001),
                df2.assign(store=1002),
                df3.assign(store=1003)], axis=0)

df.groupby('store')['Total'].sum()
```

yields

```
store
1001    32
1002    92
1003     0
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

Depending on the number of Excel files you may consider a way to automatically generate the list of store IDs / Excel file names.